# Wanna search in results from webservice and show user the results

Tags: rest, flutter, dart

i build a service that i can call like this:

```
Future<List<User>> fetchUser(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://mywebsite.org/users/search?q=HolyFreak'));
}

class User {
  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String name;
  final String user_name;

  User({this.uid, this.email, this.name, this.user_name});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Asset(
      uid: json['uid'] as String,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      user_name: json['user_name'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

the service-call returns me:

```
[{"uid":"Udfsgd324dsgf345d5","email":"me@you.com","name":"John Doe","user_name":"HolyFreak"}]
```

Now I want to build a new form, where the user can search for users and choose from the search results.
I have a TextFormField:

```
              TextFormField(
                controller: userController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search for the username',
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter name';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) => _user = value,
              ),
```

I also added a listener to be able to listen for inputchanges from the user:

```dart
  void initState() {
    userController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();

    userController.addListener(_listenUserController);
  }

  _listenUserController() {
    print("User: ${userController.text}");
  }
```

After this I can access the search data in my widget with "Searchresult(user[index].name)".

What I want: I want the user to klick into username field.
He/she starts typing the first letters of the name and if users does not type for a second the webservice gets called and shows the searchresults in the dropdown of the current field, so user can choose.

Hope you can understand what I am looking for. It would be nice, if you could show me an example where I can get an idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like [find_dropdown](https://github.com/davidsdearaujo/find_dropdown) which does exactly what you asking.

you can provide a simple list and if the users search or change the text you can then call the request and fetch new data to be displayed and then the user can select from that list.